# Draw many markers on a picture using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps

What is the efficient way of drawing many markers on a picture (a local map) using Qt?

I am using QGraphicsview/scene and I need markers to be selectable and draggable.

My problem can be exactly reporduced by using Qt's 40000 chips example. In the example, you can zoom in and out.

When you zoom out to the lowest level (where your can see all the chips), everything just became painfully lag (including selection and dragging).

My code is modified from the chips example, so it has the same behavior.
I need to drag many items (1000+) together smoothly.

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Do I have to painfully implement my own drawing engine using OpenGL?

Comment: Is it the same without the picture ? Do you have some code to show ?

Comment: Yes, without the picture, the same. My code is rather straight forward, I actually just copied the "chips" example from qt, then I modify the chips into a little square. Then use the mouse to select 300+ chips and drag them. It also becomes quite lag.

Comment: The example was fast, but became slow when you changed the items to be draggable ?

Comment: In the example, the items are draggable from the beginning. Even if I did not change anything, it is quite slow when I try to drag 300+ items.

Comment: IMO if your problem is in fact visible in the unmodified example, you should say so in the question. It would be reproducible by others, that could help. And stating clearly if it's related to static drawing of drawing-during-drag.

Comment: Thks, please see the edited question.

Comment: The behavior I've seen on my machine is that the 40K demo has no lag even zoomed out and with antialiasing, except in OpenGL mode where it lags when zoomed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104675/discussion-between-nyaruko-and-ilya).

Answer (score 3):

> Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Switching from debug to release mode improves this *a lot*.

If there's still lag during drag, display of moving parts can be disabled or restricted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the below code into the paint function of the items:
void Chip::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*>tempList =  this->scene()->items(this->boundingRect(),Qt::IntersectsItemShape,Qt::DescendingOrder,QTransform());
if(tempList.size()>5)
{
   for(int index = 4; index < tempList.size() ; index ++)
   {
       tempList.at(index)->setVisible(false);
   }
   this->scene()->update();
}
//...rest of the paint code in the example goes here...
}
```

My understanding:
The cost of redraw resulted from a drag = LOD(level of details) x number of items

when we overlay too many items together(number of items is large) AND we zoom in see the details (LOD is large), the redraw becomes expensive.

One possible way to keep the complexity low would be to limit the number of times that we draw. I think it makes sense to just draw the times that are on top and keep the rest not-visible(therefore, not to be painted).

Not sure if QT has a automatic function for doing this automatic and in a smart way.